# Starting httpd: httpd: bad user name online--1

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, httpd, plesk

My OS is CentOS 6.x, Plesk 12.x

I removed Qmail and installed Postfix from Plesk then httpd gone away. 
Here are the errors I am facing:

```
[root@centos ~]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: bad user name online--1
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@centos ~]# cd /etc/init.d;
[root@centos init.d]# ./httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 163 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ldap.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ldap.so: undefined symbol: apr_ldap_ssl_init
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@centos init.d]#
```

I restarted the server and even commented line 163 but still same problem and all of our domains become offline with message`502 Bad Gateway`

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://kb.plesk.com/en/116191

I followed the refereed article and used this command:
`/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all`

and when I tried `service httpd restart` then everything started working fine for me